# Save arguments for later Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

The title of this question is probably misleading. I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this concept. I want to pass all of the arguments into a function, but call it with those arguments *later*.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
function copyRecords(userId, options) {
    const getRecordsWrapper = (userId, options) => () => getRecords(userId, options);
    abstractionService = new MyAbstractionService(getRecordsWrapper);
    ...etc
}
```

This is where I would save and later call the function:

```
class MyAbstractionService {
    constructor(getRecords) {
        this.getRecords = getRecords;
    }
    performSomeAction() {
        return this.getRecords();
    }
}
```

I need to do this because `getRecords` takes different arguments in different areas, and I want to abstract them into one service without having to pass a bunch of arguments into the service. That will get messy, as I need to do this for some other functions as well.

Am I thinking about this correctly? Is there another way to do this besides having a function return another function which returns my function? Also, not sure if this is important but `getRecords` returns a `Promise`. I don't want to start working on the `Promise` until I'm in the abstraction service later though.

Comment: In short, there is nothing wrong with what you're doing. You've correctly intuited that by using a higher order function, you can avoid repetitiously passing the same arguments every time you call `getRecords`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In functional programming terms, what you're describing is [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), and in JavaScript you can achieve the simplest idea of it using the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
const getRecordsWrapper = getRecords.bind(null, userId, options);
```

The first argument passed to `bind` is the function context (the `this`) of the to-be-called-later function, while the rest of the arguments are passed as regular arguments.

If you're looking for a fully-featured functional programming framework in JavaScript, take a look at [Ramda.js](https://ramdajs.com/) (for example).

Comment: This isn't strictly "currying" but rather an example of a higher order function.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I almost tagged the question as currying... didn't pay enough attention in my paradigms course apparently. `bind` looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bind()` is a good idea. Here's an alternative. Leaving it up to readers which is preferred.

```
function copyRecords(userId, options) {
  return () => {
    return getRecords(userId, options);
  }
};
```

Note that this is pretty much identical to:

```
function copyRecords(userId, options) {
  return getRecords.bind(this, userId, options);
};
```

So it comes down to a subjective preference.

Answer (score 1):

As *partial application* is a common problem, there is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-partial-application) to support that directly in javascript without `.bind`. If the proposal gets through, it will look like:

```
new MyAbstractionService(getRecords(userId, options, ...))
```

Comment: Oh god I need this proposal to happen.